# HTML output problems

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am writing a website with python and jinja2 in google app engine.  My html page is showing this on the page:

```
Status: 200
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 432
```

Any idea where this problem is coming from? Also, why is {{ initial_city }} not displaying the results?

My main.py script is:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from models import Deal
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2


#databasestuff
deal = Deal(title='Hello',
        description='Deal info here',
        city='New York')
deal.put()
print deal


jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render())


class DealHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    def get_deals(choose_city, update=False):
        key = str(choose_city)
        all_deals = memcache.get(key)
        return all_deals

    choose_city = self.request.get('c')
    try:
        initial_city = str(choose_city)
        choose_city = initial_city
    except ValueError:
        initial_city = 0
        choose_city = initial_city


    template = jinja_environment.get_template('deal.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render())




class ContentHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    template = jinja_environment.get_template('content.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/deal', DealHandler),
                           ('/content', ContentHandler)],
                          debug=True)
```

My html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Deallzz: Chosen City: {{ initial_city }}
    </title>
  </head>
  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display initial_city, pass the variable to the template using the render method:

`self.response.out.write(template.render(initial_city = initial_city))`

Answer (score 2):

Its the "print deal" that is causing the problem.  Its being output before any response.write

Comment: thanks! the message is gone now.  Any idea why {{ initial_city }} is not displaying the city chosen in the index page.
My index.html page script is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dealzz Home!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <CENTER>
<form action="/deal">
 <p>I am travelling to (choose city):</p>
 <select name="c">
  <option value="New York">New York City</option>
  <option value="Miami">Miami</option>
  <option value="Toronto">Toronto</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Find me travel deals!">
</form>
</CENTER>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: The print statement is being executed during import.  If the request starts an instance then the import is run.  Caching of the instance /handler means the print is then not executed till the next import. You don't have a 'selected' attribute any of the options so no item will be currently selected.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the [headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header) of the HTML page. You should provide more informations/code of what you are trying now.